# Quadric surface reduced form

Tags: computational-geometry

I was just wondering, is there any way to determine which surface is the one given by the equation in general implicit form [image: general implicit form]

Without calculating the eigenvalues and basis vectors etc.
Or if you preferably know the code to transform one form into another in any language it would be really useful to reference it here.

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: This looks more like a cubic surface to me, unless $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j$ are parameters and $x,y,z,w$ are coordinates. Is this the case?

Comment: Elliptic vs hyperbolic vs ... cannot be determined for generic symbolic coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

```
M = {{a, b, c, d},
     {b, e, f, g},
     {c, f, h, i},
     {d, g, i, j}};
NullSpace[M]
```

will give you the null eigenvector(s) for $\{x,y,z,w\}$ without going through `Eigensystem`. If you just want to know the number of such null eigenvectors,

```
Length[M] - MatrixRank[M]
```